# How to hide the autofill suggestions js

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code

```
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";

            }
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to hide all elements unless they are searched for.

Comment: you can hide it simply by <input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML you can use this:
[autocomplete="off"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp).
This will work for: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.

For HTML4 there is no suggested way to do so, as "Autofill" is a browser-based technique.